# google analytics double counting conversions

Tags: google-analytics

I sell a PDF that is delivered on the same page that is being used to count conversions in Google Analytics.  Will GA count multiple visits to this page over a couple of days? For example, person downloads PDF, a few days later they revisit the page and download the pdf again.  Their has only been one conversion but multiple visits.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's better if you post your code here. Without that I cannot tell for sure.

Probably yes, GA will count a conversion each time your customer visit the download page, because you probably define it as your goal for conversions, correct? I think the easiest way to avoid this is to define another page as your goal or provide the subsequent downloads in other place.

Anyway, is possible to configure GA or your page to prevent this behavior, but is necessary to know more about your page...